# Absolute convergence $\frac{(-1)^n}{n \ln n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_2^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n \ln n}$$

So I claim that it is absolutely convergent because it only coverges when it is an absolute value. This is wrong but I don't see how.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \dfrac 1{n(\ln n)^p} $ converges if and only if $p > 1$

Comment: p is greater than 1 I have n^1 and lnn which is higher than 0 so I get n^>1

Comment: No, it is not. In the absolute value of your sum, $p = 1$.

Comment: The p refers to the exponent of the factor $(\ln n)^p$. In your case, you have that the  $(\ln n)^1 = \ln n$

Comment: @Amzoti Why? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You are mistakenly applying the $p$ test, which applies only to series of the form $\sum \frac 1{n^p}$. Your series is not of that form.

Comment: Your series does converge, John. But it is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Alternating Series Test? The Leibniz criteria? It applies to a series of this form, which although not absolutely convergent, does converge.

Comment: @Amzoti The alternate series does converge, I thought that was clear. It is the series of absolute values that diverges.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I actually did not read the entire post and it might have been helpful to address both points in the responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is written below is really the Cauchy Condensation Test, without mention of Cauchy, and with calculations concretely carried out.  We could work with partial sums, but we will do things somewhat more informally. Our series is 
$$\left( \frac{1}{2\log 2}\right)+\left( \frac{1}{3\log 3}+\frac{1}{4\log 4}\right)+ 
\left( \frac{1}{5\log 5}+\frac{1}{6\log 6}+\frac{1}{7\log 7}+\frac{1}{8\log 8}\right)+\cdots$$

We have $1$ term of $\frac{1}{2\log 2}$, $2$ terms each $\ge \frac{1}{4\log 4}$, and $4$ terms each $\ge \frac{1}{8\log 8}$, and so on. So our sum is greater than 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{1}{\log 4}+\frac{1}{\log 8}+\frac{1}{\log 16}+\cdots\right).$$
Note that $\log 4=2\log 2$, $\log 6=3\log 2$, $\log 16=4\log 2$, and so on. So our sum is greater than 
$$\frac{1}{2\log 2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right).$$
But $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$ (undramatically) blows up. It follows that our original series diverges.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Look at $$\int_2^a\frac{dx}{x\log  x}\;\;;\;\;a\to\infty$$

Note that $$\left(\log\log x\right)^\prime=\frac{1}{x\log x}$$

Thus $$\int_2^a\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\log\log a-\log\log 2$$

And this diverges as $a\to\infty$. The integral test says the series **of absolute values** diverges.

**ADD** Since $$\frac{1}{n\log n}\to 0$$ and the sequence is decreasing, Leibniz' test says the **series of alternate** terms converges.

Comment: I know that it converges

Comment: @John That is where you're mistaken.

Comment: No way, x^r with r>1 will converge and that is greater than 1.

Comment: @John I promise it diverges. Use Barrow's rule to find the integral over $[2,a]$ then let $a\to\infty$.

Comment: I am just using the p series rule.

Comment: @John The "$p$ series rule" works when the series is of the form $$\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$$ Your series is **not** of that form.

Comment: @John: whatever you use should give the same result: the series $\sum\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges... the approach above is to see that $\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ has same behavior as $\ln \ln N$, which goes to $\infty$ when $N\to\infty$ (this "has same behavior" argument can easily be made rigorous via a comparison between sum and integral).

Comment: But you can make it into that form like is often done. $n^1$ and $ln n$ make it greater than 1

Comment: No. For **any** $p > 1$, $n\ln n = o(n^p)$, which means that $\frac{1}{n^p}=o\left(\frac{1}{n\ln n}\right)$.

Comment: But I have an n times an n to some fraction power.

Comment: No. A logarithm is not a power at all — it is exponentially smaller.

Comment: But it is greater than 0, it certainly isn't 0, and it isn't a negative exponent so something that is positive plus 1 is > 1

Comment: @John You need to accept the fact the series diverges.

Comment: @John: No! $\ln n$ is *not* a power of $n$. What you're saying is equivalent to claiming that $e^n$ "must be of the form $n^k$, because it is greater that $n$". There are other functions than powers — a logarithm is negligible in front of any power strictly positive.

Comment: So magic? I don't think that is an acceptable answer I can write down. "You just need to accept that this diverges, no further proof needed"

Comment: @John I gave you the proof above.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff You never even determined if it is conditionally divergent or whatever and I don't really see any of what you did, you just wrote loglog for some reason

Comment: @John The series is conditionally convergent. Reason: by Leibniz' test the series converges. By the integral test, the series of absolute values diverges. By $\log \log x$ I mean $\log(\log(x))$

Comment: @John: you have *two* different proofs in the answers. You just don't accept them, because you cling to the (erroneous) idea that $\ln x$ "must be" greater asymptotically that $x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 0$. This is not the case.

Comment: The posted series converges, though it is not absolutely convergent.  Peter, please address the convergence of the alternating series.

Comment: @amWhy Done. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @amWhy: Peter proved that the series was not *absolutely* convergent — which was the main point of the original question of the OP ("So I claim that it is absolutely convergent"). It is indeed *conditionally* convergent, by the alternating series test (the absolute value is monotonically decreasing, and the sign alternates).

Comment: @Clement C. Exactly, that's all I was hoping. To address both the non-absolute convergence, AND the conditional convergence.

Comment: @John I hope you understand the proof now. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I don't understand it at all, I don't really understand any of this I have never seen a sequence or a series until a couple days ago so I don't understand any of this at all and I have about 60 rules I need to memorize by tomorrow.

Comment: Do you want to go on the chat to discuss it?

Comment: @John You can drop by [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) and maybe we can clear things out.

Answer (score 3):

Another cool way of proving that 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n}
$$
diverges is to use [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). If you let $f(n)=\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ (which is non-increasing for $n\ge 2$) we get that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{n}f(2^n)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{2^n\ln(2^{n})}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln2}=\frac{1}{\ln2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
$$
Since harmonic series diverges, we conclude that the above sum also diverges.

Comment: +1 CCT is not hard to prove and is very, very useful, for example, for $p$ series or series of this form.

Comment: I don't have time to learn more rules.

Comment: @John These are not mere rules. Rather, they are theorems. Is someone rushing you?

Comment: Well I have about 60 to learn so far and I don't have a single one memorized so I can't add another

Comment: @John: CCT is quite powerful. If you learn it now (which I am sure won't take much of your time), you can use it on many other series questions.

Comment: I think I need a few more years of math before I can read wikipedia articles, or at least a translation book.

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$u_n=\frac{1}{n\log n}$$
so the harmonic series
$$2^nu_{2^n}=\frac{1}{n\log 2}$$
is divergent hence by the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)  the given series isn't absolute convergent.

Comment: Nice work, Sami, as usual. (On a different note: Do you get terribly bothered by undeserved down-votes?) I ask because I do...When I deserve it, I can deal with it. But when I feel targeted and for no reason, it bothers me.

Comment: Yes in my early at this site I was too much sensitive and an  unjustified down-vote bothers me a lot  but now after more than a year I feel more indifferent to  down-votes; it looks like I am now vaccinated;-)

Comment: I need that vaccine to not get bothered by unjustified down-votes. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value of the general term $a_n$ of the series is $\frac{1}{n\ln n}$. To see why it diverges, you can do a comparison series/integral — hint: $$\frac{d}{dx}\ln\ln x = \frac{1}{x\ln x}$$

Comment: (more generally, series with general term $a_n=\frac{1}{n^\alpha\ln^\beta n}$ only converge when **(a)** $\alpha > 1$, $\beta$ arbitrary or **(b)** $\alpha=1$ and $\beta > 1$.
In any other case, the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.